# Fixed position of Regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I have the following string and the layout is fixed so I use the following method to retrieve information

```
$A = "00035king"
$Regex = '(.{5})(.{4})'
$Replace = '$2,$1'
$A = $A -replace $Regex, $Replace
```

The result is `king,00035`. However, I would like to remove leading zeros for my second section, which changes it from `00035` to `35`. Is there anyway I can do it or any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may match 0 to 4 zeros at the start of the string followed with 1 to 5 chars, and then check if there are 5 chars from the start of string consumed.

Use

```
'^0{0,4}(.{1,5})(?<=^.{5})(.{4})$'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AIJ2ug/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `0{0,4}` - 0 to 4 zeros
- `(.{1,5})` - Group 1: 1 to 5 chars
- `(?<=^.{5})` - a positive lookbehind requiring that there must be 5 chars immediately before the current location from the start of string
- `(.{4})` - Group 2: any four chars
- `$` - end of string (or `\z` will match the very end of string).

Comment: Thank you for your kindly help, Wiktor.